# Google Chrome Frame и большой Canvas

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, javascript, html5

Необходимо к проекту подключить Google Chrome Frame. Проект полностью на Canvas, огромные полотна. Всё отлично, он всё подхватывает, если бы не одна проблема. `<canvas>` работает ровно до того момента, пока его площадь не перевалит за 2^16. То, есть, скажем, холст размером 256x256 - работает без малейших нареканий. Стоит поставить размер 257x256 - отрисовка не происходит или происходит только один раз.

Проверял на IE7 и IE8.

Вот ссылка для теста: http://theshock.github.com/trash/chrome-frame-fail.html

Вот пример того, как оно выглядит в IE8:

[image: Скриншот]

Есть ссылки, идеи, может какие-то предположения, куда можно копать, чтобы решить эту проблему?

Comment: В гугле все работает

Comment: Спасибо, я знаю, что в Google Chrome всё работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, это был баг GPU в Chrome в VMWare:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175149